# System Crash with graphics

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I have two Nvidia GeForce GTX 660 cards (one MSI and one gigabyte) and they both have 2 GB onboard RAM. To go with this I have an Intel core i5 3550 (@3.30GHz).

Also, I am running Win 7 64 with 32 GB RAM. In the past, playing Skyrim I would have a random complete system crash. This is not a crash to desktop... this is a power failure...full reboot... my system failed... In the hundreds of hours of reading I have never come across a solution and was relegated to chalking it up to Skyrim.

Today I have the exact same event playing Shadow of Mordor. I am at a complete loss... I have no overheating issues (checked the CPU and GPU temps over a hundred times), not a power issue (I have 1000W system and have gone so far as to get out the multimeter and check the rails), and apparently not just Skyrim. Does anyone have any idea for the cause?

Some other info:

- My PSU is the [Ultra X3 ULT-HE1000X](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2395/9). I get no BSOD, no crash to desktop...this sends  my system straight to a reboot with the warning that "windows was improperly shut down" on restart.
- Recent memtest86: no issues
- Recent (within a month) reinstall of Win 7

Comment: not enough information yet to even guess. You could make a few changes.  In system Properties, Advanced tab, Startup and Recovery, system failure, make sure that  "Automatically Restart" in Not selected.  Now we get a nice BSOD instead :-)  In your motherboard bios/uefi get into the power section (different in different boards) and find the ACoff or AC power restore , or whatever it is called and set it to Disable, Off or whatever keeps it from powering up after a power off.  With those 2 changes made correct, what you say about How this problem shows up then, will be more info.

Comment: OK. I have unchecked "auto restart" and I believe i have fixed the power in the BIOS. Now i get a screen freeze and hang. I have to manually restart the system. I could not find a dump file for errors. I went int S&R and changed to "small minidump" from kernel and I will see what I get,

Comment: Now it is less likely to be the PSU or the motherboards power settings etc. A gpu is likely to reset itself, that did not happen, so it is less likely to be a gpu processor issue, or board timings.  next i would want to hard test items as saperate as I could in software. Like running prime in small fft beats on the cpu, running prime custom selecting most of the memory beats on the ram, and running furmark or occts gpu (processor) and Artifacts (ram). These things are all very harsh and could spot what fails first in a hard load.  Must watch temps when using, must read program disclaimers

Comment: So..interestingly I was playing the other day...after i made the power changes above and the whole system crashed again... does this point toward the PSU?

Comment: No it does not lean in that direction, Previously just dropping out could have been motherboard or PSU protections (or fails) slamming the power off.  By changing a few things you know that specific thing is not happening, so it could be cpu or ram or even gpu problem, software & drivers possibility that causes this.  Doing the hard testing sort-of discounts the software more because these tests are just simple raw slamming, and not complex interworking softwares that can also cause crashing, the hard tests would concentrate more on the stability of the hardwares, with simple processes.

Comment: 9 hours of prime in small fft beats on the cpu - no errors. FurMark next

Comment: Ran Furmark without an issue. Unsure what info may be useful from it

Comment: trying to get 2 tests in the gpu , one testing the gpu processing, done by rendering some hard scene. the second is artifact testing or ram for the gpu. Because ram on the gpu is often poorly cooled, and cooled different, and does not get a thermal responce from the fan.   9hrs prime small :-) cpu processing solid. Furmark render only GPU processing solid. Now it leans more to GPU drivers, and other software.

Comment: So now I have run Uningines Heaven with no issues...I also ran video memory stress test on both GTX 660 cards and received no errors. I did run occts for a short while with no issues but I did notice that my cpu seems to be running about 5% overclocked... I'm not sure why.

Comment: little overclocks and turbos should not be a problem, a person might turn them off for testing, but prime small is torturous if you survived it your very stable in the cpu.  If the BCLK which is the base frequency for most of the stuff including the PCI-E and therefore GPU was set above 100 it could cause a problem of that type. You did not mention temperatures, things seem to get more (intermittantly) glitchy over 80*C , GPU thermal profiles allow high temps, manuel fan settings can be used to test there.

Comment: So my max gpu temp  running furmark was 60 degrees with about 105% tdp. My cpu temps were fine as well. My BCLK is set at 100 and the CPU is locked so I cannot change it or make it anything else. I have been trying to figure this out for well over a year and im really getting frustrated... I do appreciate the help and am willing to check or try anything with this thing.... maybe switch to AMD...

Comment: Interesting way to stop turbos without playing with bios/uefi:   In windows Power  (make a custom profile) "Change Plan Settings" , "Change advanced Power settings" , "Processor power management" , "Maximum Power State" , set to 99% Use that profile and turbo stops, the cpu runs more normal. Add that to a GPU "underclock" with small 50-100 lower frequency locked down, with manuel high fan. The whole thing then runs at ~90% and not above.  That does nothing for any bclck, just holds everything down conviently without leaving the os.

Comment: I cannot believe it... after almost 2 years of this issue I finally figured it out. My system failed and ACTUALLY created a BSOD and dump file... It turned out there was a problem with the driver for the firewire adapter. Apparently this is a known issue and there is a hotfix for it on some systems.  The hotfix does not apply to my system for some reason but since I don't use the firewire anyway... I disabled it in my BIOS. Running Skyrim and Shadow hard for hours with no issues.. I really do appreciate all the help and patience on your end!

Comment: Please answer your own question, to help others who would search for the same problem.

Comment: well... not fixed. I am coming to the conclusion that the motherboard is to blame...something i suspected a while ago but really didnt want to have to change.  Thanks for the help all the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit time consuming, but an effective method for finding faulty hardware.  When you have a complicated setup like this, troubleshooting can be difficult with so many moving parts so removing components can help to narrow down whats wrong.  Some of these might seem like no brainers, but going through the whole process should give you a better idea of what's going on if not an answer.

Here are some things you can try that will keep you gaming.  The idea here is to play until your computer crashes, then move to the next step.  If it doesn't crash at a point, then we're closer to our answer.  You didn't mention how often this happens.  Is it once a day?  Once a week?

1. Ramp down to the *lowest* graphics setting, play game with current system.
2. Remove video card #2, ramp back up to a high graphics setting and play.  Repeat with Video card #1.
3. Take out both video cards.  Load your drivers for the internal graphics processing for the intel core i5 3550 (make sure to double check what socket you're using) and play at the highest setting you can.
4. Remove sticks of ram one at a time and keep playing.

As you are removing components, get a can of compressed air and go to town on your rig and each piece of hardware as well as the sockets they were in.  If there is a lot of dust build up I would do a complete overhaul. A little TLC never hurt.

Best of luck and let us know how things go!